# Why does this code has a time complexity of O(N*N)?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

```
int a = 0;
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (j = N; j > i; j--) {
        a = a + i + j;
    }
}
```

Why does this code has time complexity of O(N*N) ? Are all  nested loops with n,m,q,.... bounds have a complexity of O(n*m*q....) even though few iterations of the loops will not happen?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33858889/why-is-the-big-o-complexity-of-this-algorithm-on

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44085863/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-the-following-algorithm/44086434#44086434

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is that constant factors are ignored in Big-O notation.

Your outer loop runs `N` times, while the inner loop runs on average `N/2` times for each of the outer iterations.

This gives `O(N * 1/2 * N)` executions of the statements within the inner loop. Since we ignore constant factors, we end up with `O(N * N)` which is `O(N^2)`.

The reason for omitting constants is simple: Big-O notation is about what happens when `N` is big. If you look at it this way - `O((N^2)/2)` - you see that increasing `N` has much more influence in the term, than whether or not we omit the division by two.

Comment: nice explanation. thank you

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say all nested loops have that complexity, but this one certainly does.  The number of iterations through the inner loop is something like this (there might be an off-by-one error):

- i = 0:  N times
- i = 1:  N - 1 times
- i = 2:  N - 2 times
- . . .
- i = N-1: 1 times
- i = N:  0 times

Let's count the total number of times the innermost code is called.  In this case, you can figure this out arithmetically. The innermost code is executed about `N * (N + 1) / 2` times (this is the [sum of elements from 1 to N](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29549836/how-to-find-the-sum-of-all-numbers-between-1-and-n-using-javascript)).  This simplifies to `0.5 * N^2 + 0.5 * N` and that has a complexity of `N^2`.

Comment: Instead of saying "that has a complexity of N^2", I'd say "since Big-O notation cares about the dominant factor in asymptotic behavior, that's equivalent to N^2"

Comment: shouldn't it be N*(N+0)/2 ?